# Replace characters in file that is being written at the same time

Tags: php, python, regex, replace, reddit

I'm trying to write some (pre-fetched) reddit comment parameters to a PHP array in another file called `post-info.php`. Here's the python code that writes it:

```
with open('post-info.php','w') as myfile:
                myfile.write("""<?php\n$settings = array(\n 'submitter' => '{0}',\n 'body' => "{1}",\n 'permalink' => '{2}',\n);\n?>""".format(str(comment.author), comment.body, comment.permalink))
                myfile.close()
```

This, however, is kind of annoying because sometimes reddit comments have quotes in them which cancel out the quotes surrounding the comment body. I'd like to replace the quotes with different quotes so it won't cancel them out.

How do I go about replacing characters in a file that is already being written?

Comment: Why don't you just escape `comment.body` before it is written?

Comment: @aa333 I'm kinda dumb at python. What do you mean by that and how would I do it?

Comment: `import re; re.escape(comment.body);` That'll escape every non alphanumeric.

Comment: @aa333 But I don't want to remove them all together, quotes are still important if they're there. I just want to change, for example, a `"` to a `'`

Comment: `comment.body.replace("\"","\'")` That'll just replace all `"` with `'`

Comment: @aa333 Perfect, that problem seems solved. One new one though: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u20ac' in position 31: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: You probably have Unicode characters in your `comment.body` that don't have ascii equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

Using `repr(comment.body)` may be your best solution here.